# SQL: Filter based on criteria

Tags: sql, yql

I am using Yahoo's YQL to retrieve data about my Fantasy Football league. YQL is very similar to SQL.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/XtnbGfxs) is the output of `

```
select * 
from fantasysports.leagues.standings 
where league_key='331.l.777399'
```

How would I filter this to just display "points_for" for a team if I supply team_id

I thought it would be

```
select * 
from fantasysports.leagues.standings 
where league_key='331.l.777399' 
and standings.teams.team.%.team_id='2'
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
select points_for
from fantasysports.leagues.standings
where league_key='331.l.777399'
and standings.teams.team.%.team_id='2'
```

Comment: Next time don't make a line of code as far as a runway big enough for a Jumbo.

Comment: No no, in the code I used, even when I do `standings.teams.team.%.team_id='2'`, it does not provide anything